# Cannot truncate table in Cassandra 2.0.2

Tags: cassandra

I get the following error: Unable to complete request: one or more nodes were unavailable.

I have a single node in my cluster. All other queries seem to work just great, the node is obviously available.

My cassandra.yaml is standard out of the box, except that I've changed the listen_address and rpc_address from localhost to the IP address of the server.

```
CREATE TABLE browse_document_tree (
    tree INT, 
    pub INT,
    rhpath VARCHAR, 
    atime TIMESTAMP,
    ccount INT,
    ncount INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (tree)
) WITH gc_grace_seconds = 864000;

CREATE TABLE browse_document_node (
    hpath VARCHAR, 
    tree INT, 
    title VARCHAR,
    stitle VARCHAR,
    dtype VARCHAR,
    dispdtype VARCHAR,
    ord INT,
    pord INT,
    page BIGINT, 
    spage BIGINT,
    ccount INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (hpath, tree)
) WITH gc_grace_seconds = 172800;

CREATE TABLE bdn_index_page (
    page BIGINT, 
    tree INT,
    hpath VARCHAR,
    PRIMARY KEY (page, tree)
) WITH gc_grace_seconds = 172800;

CREATE TABLE bdn_index_story_page (
    spage BIGINT, 
    tree INT,
    hpath VARCHAR,
    PRIMARY KEY (spage, tree)
) WITH gc_grace_seconds = 172800;

CREATE TABLE bdn_index_pub (
    tree INT,
    pord INT,
    hpath VARCHAR,
    PRIMARY KEY (tree, pord)
) WITH gc_grace_seconds = 172800;

CREATE TABLE bdn_index_child (
    phpath VARCHAR,
    tree INT,
    ord INT,
    hpath VARCHAR,
    PRIMARY KEY (phpath, tree, ord)
) WITH gc_grace_seconds = 172800;
```

Comment: What is the replication factor for your keyspace?

Comment: 1. I have a single node.

Comment: You can still have replication factor > 1 with a single node. Can you paste your schema?

Answer (score 1):

A workaround for this is to drop the table and re-create the schema. This seems to at least work and would achieve the same effect. Perhaps it is more efficient too since there are no tombstones to deal with.